# Questions about domain blocking in SpamAssasin with * wildcards, etc

Tags: exchange-2007, spamassassin, untangle

So, as of last week I've [implemented a blocklist on our Untangle](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1413439-manual-blacklist-cf-file-for-untangle-etc-spamassassin-does-not-work-why?page=1&source=homepage-feed#entry-5454461) (which runs Apache SpamAssassin behind the scenes). For the most part it's working, but there is still some spam getting through that I want to block. For example I have blocked this:

blacklist_from *@mail.eu

Yet spam from address like this are still getting through (3 new just this morning): 
*@aweerr.caprav.eu
*@ftwes.maroonh.eu
*@swefgy.sinsult.eu

So my questions:
- Does the "mail" in *@mail.eu not act a wildcard as well? So, for example, anything from any@any.eu should be blocked, correct?
- For sub-domains (like *@swefgy.sinsult.eu) should I make a rule like this (woud this work)? 
blacklist_from *@*.eu
and/or
blacklist_from *@mail.*.eu

Also, if anyone knows of a free service where I can get a "throw away" email account with something OTHER than .com (.point, .eu, .work, etc) that would be very helpful with my testing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the internet is concerned, host.example.eu and example.eu are two completely different domains. Therefore if you want to block sub domains then you will need to have something like @ * .*.eu (if the tool that you are using can support the double wildcard).